# Google Drive API: Change Slide During The Presentation

Tags: android, jquery, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need to get some work done with the Google Drive API for Android. My aim is to control via the API the current slide of a presentation, so on a computer a presentation is opened in "present"-View. Is there a way to get the user's opened presentation and change then with the API the slide? 
Some research didn't help me, so maybe you have some information?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's doable if you've written your own presentation app that utilizes Drive somehow. If you mean the default presentation function when viewing slides, then **no**, the Drive SDK has no control over that. Also, if you're trying to utilize the Android API in hopes it'd be some sort of remote, I suggest you look into Google Cast instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Drive APIs provide file management, rather than direct access to the viewing apps.

As far as I'm aware there isn't an API that will allow you to access a user's Slides viewing state across devices.